# Bootstrap Navbar horizontal align

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

With the structure:

```
---------------------------------------------- 
 Logo Text                  item1 item2_1 item3
                                  item2_2
----------------------------------------------
```

What I want is center horizontally the logo, text and the items. The `item2` is too long and has 2 parts. I've tried but I can't get it.

The code is the following:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#?>"><img src="Logo.png" style="height: 25px;" class="d-inline-block align-middle">Text</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item2_1<br>item2_2</a></li>
        <li class="menuletra"><a href="#">item3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar {
min-height: 70px;
padding-top: 5px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
z-index: 100;}
```

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a live example of your work on something like jsFiddle.net or codepen.io.

Comment: please check the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ztm8yoq5/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center the text horizontally in the drop-down menu, simply set `text-align: center` on `.navbar`. If you want to bring both the logo and the text in a bit from the edges of the screen in the desktop view, you'll want to add a `max-width` to `.navbar > .container`.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.navbar {
  min-height: 70px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 100;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar > .container {
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#?>"><img src="http://placehold.it/100" style="height: 25px;" class="d-inline-block align-middle">Text</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item2_1<br>item2_2</a></li>
        <li class="menuletra"><a href="#">item3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, maybe my explanation was not correct, check the pictures, the upper one is your exmaple and the next one is what I want:   [named hyperlinks](https://picijo.com/uploads/img/7000_0.jpg)